# Calculated column without a relationship between tables using Power Pivot

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I would like to calculate a HFI Rate but keep getting an error (or false data) because Power Pivot is not recognizing the relationship between table 1 and table 3.

Is there a way to create a calculated column that will do this task for me without having a recognized relationship?

- Table 1:  Many rows, dates, and repeated product numbers
- Table 2:  Product numbers are not repeated
- Table 3:  Production by Month and Year for each Product Number (product numbers are repeated)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Table 3 I added two calculated columns.

1. HFIQTY: calculate(sum(HFIs[HFI Quantity]))
2. DefectRate:  [HFIQTY]/[Qty Prod]*

*I found out that my production number was a gross number and not a net number so I did not need to add back in the HFI'd number.

I still have not figured out how to relate the tables so that I can filter out defects that are outside of our control but maybe I will at another time.